# Method not working - customize cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have custom `UITableViewCell` class in which i wrote a method, to proper initialize cell content and appearance. Now i want cell to be round and with border. Firstly, i wrote:

```
-(void)cornerCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell withImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView{

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 33;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 82, 0, 0);
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
}
```

Then, in my method (which i use to fill the cell content) i wrote following:

```
Declared in myCell.m


 -(void)fillCellWithTableViewIndex:(NSInteger)index withTableView:(UITableView*)myTableView withImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView{

...some code

[self cornerCell:self withImageView:self.myCellImageView];
```

After this, i call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in my `ViewController`:

Declared in viewController.m

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

...some code

[cell fillCellWithTableViewIndex:indexPath.row withTableView:tableView withImageView:cell.myCellImageView];

return cell;

}
```

Its not working. However, when i call

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

...some code 


    [cell fillCellWithTableViewIndex:indexPath.row withTableView:tableView withImageView:cell.myCellImageView];

    cell.myCellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 33;
    cell.myCellImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 82, 0, 0);
    cell.myCellImageView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;

    return cell;

}
```

Its work, but it look ugly and against general concept of clear and concise code. Why my first attempt isn't working?

I hope i describe everything clear, please, try to figure out what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method, you're not using the passed-in `imageView`, you're using the cell's built-in `cell.imageView`, which is evidently not the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)cornerCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell withImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView{

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 33;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 82, 0, 0);
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
}
```

Why don't you using `imageView` parameter at all?

`cell.imageView` means you using common `.imageView` property, but seems like you want `cell.myCellImageView` - your custom property